Using scipy.optimize library to find minimum of a function
initially I write this code through many iterations and it works fine.
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize

# Define the sigmoid function


def sigmoid(x):
    return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x))

# Define the sigmoid-based loss function


def sigmoid_loss(theta, X, y_true):
    return np.mean((sigmoid(X @ theta) - y_true)**2)


# Generate synthetic data
np.random.seed(0)  # Set random seed for reproducibility
m = 1000
n = 5
X = np.random.randn(m, n)

# True values as a column vector
theta_true = np.array(
    [-0.4277, -0.5794, 0.9260, 0.0055, -0.6345]).reshape(-1, 1)

y_true = sigmoid(X @ theta_true)  # True output values (between 0 and 1)

theta_init = np.random.randn(5, 1)

tolerance = 1e-10

# Optimization using SciPy's minimize function
result_NM = minimize(sigmoid_loss, theta_init.flatten(), args=(
    X, y_true.flatten()), method='Nelder-Mead', tol=tolerance)

# result_NM = minimize(sigmoid_loss, theta_init.flatten(), args=(
#     X, y_true.flatten()), method='Nelder-Mead', tol=tolerance)

# Display optimization results
print(f'Number of iterations: {result_NM.nit}')
print(f'Optimal solution: {result_NM.x}')
print(f'Minimum value of the loss function: {result_NM.fun}')


At first it didn't work, until I tried to use .flatten() method in a function call of the function 'minimize'.
I'm not sure why is that. I know that in numpy I need to be very carefully about the actual dimensions of the data, and that is why I used .reshape(-1,1) method to be sure that matrices can multiply correctly.
So (1000,5) x (5,1) will produce vector (1000,1) and loss function is defined as a mean square error.
However, minimize function require "flatten" data, so that, for example
print(theta_init.flatten().shape)

will produce the following output (5, ), so the other dimension is "undefined", I don't understand this is the case.
Can you please explain, why minimize cannot work correctly with (5,1), but, it can with (5,)?
Thank you!
I did try to use consistent dimension when calling minimize function, and it can even provide the result, which is not a real solution.
Minimize function also generates a warning "DeprecationWarning: Use of minimize with x0.ndim != 1 is deprecated. Currently, singleton dimensions will be removed from x0"

You may need to rrad more about numpy dimensions.  A shape (5,) does not have an 'other dimension'.  It is 1d, with just one dimrnsion.  reshape(-1,1) makes a 2d array (you can call it a 'column vector', numpy doesn't).  Most of the scipy optimize functions work with 1d arrays.  The x it passes to your function will be 1d.  Read matmul docs, it is ok with 1d arrays.  A (m,n) @ (n,)=>(m,)

When I run minimize with just theta_init, I get ValueError: 'x0' must only have one dimension. As @hpaulj says, scipy only implemented minimize to work with 1D arrays. Not much more to it than that.


will produce the following output (5, ), so the other dimension is "undefined"

It's not that the other dimension is undefined. (5, ) is how Python represents a tuple with one element. This is necessary, because (5) would be ambiguous: it could mean a 5 with parentheses around it to control evaluation order. So (5,) is just an array with one dimension, i.e. a vector.

Can you please explain, why minimize cannot work correctly with (5,1), but, it can with (5,)? Thank you!

This is because of how minimize is defined:
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html

x0: ndarray, shape (n,)
Initial guess. Array of real elements of size (n,), where n is the number of independent variables.

So minimize() is defined to operate on 1D arrays. (5, 1) is a 2D array, so it's not supported.
As you've observed, you can work around this, by using .flatten() to convert higher-dimensional arrays to 1D, and using .reshape(original_shape) to restore the original shape again afterwards.

Here's how I'd adjust your code to get dimensions right.  I won't, for now, try to test it
sigmoid works with any dimension x, returning the same shape
# Define the sigmoid function
def sigmoid(x):
    return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x))

If X is (m,n), then theta should be (n,), and y_true (m,).  Result will be scalar.
# Define the sigmoid-based loss function
def sigmoid_loss(theta, X, y_true):
    return np.mean((sigmoid(X @ theta) - y_true)**2)

Setup:
# Generate synthetic data
np.random.seed(0)  # Set random seed for reproducibility
m = 1000
n = 5
X = np.random.randn(m, n)

# True values as a column vector
theta_true = np.array(
    [-0.4277, -0.5794, 0.9260, 0.0055, -0.6345]) # (n,) shape

y_true = sigmoid(X @ theta_true)  # True output values (between 0 and 1)
# (m,n)@(n,)=>(m,)

theta_init = np.random.randn(5)  # (n,)

tolerance = 1e-10

# Optimization using SciPy's minimize function
result_NM = minimize(sigmoid_loss, theta_init, args=(
    X, y_true), method='Nelder-Mead', tol=tolerance)

Basically if X is (m,n), theta_init is (n,), and y_true is (m,) this should work.
